# Why can't I kill any escorts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On my travels I often encounter Thalmor Justiciar escorting a prisoner. As a former prisoner, I once tried aiding him by slaying his escort. Sadly, the guards at the next village I encountered saw that as a vile crime.

So now I'm left wondering, **why can't I kill these lone escorts, especially when there are no eye witnesses?** Or are the Thalmor the good guys and should I let this criminal be taken to the block without inferring like a law-abiding citizen of Skyrim?

[image]

Comment: You know you can turn quest markers off for quests you're not actively pursuing, right? :P

Comment: I only follow the blue one I marked anyway @StrixVaria, besides I keep straying off the path to clear dungeons anyway :P

Comment: Title of this question had me thinking we were dealing with *yet another* dumb, misanthropic, misogynistic question about pixelated prostitutes.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - be nice;  I was just having fun with that question and it's since been closed :p

Comment: Did you attack them first, if so that causes you a bounty. or maybe it was something else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No witnesses? What do you mean, no witnesses? You're leaving the prisoner alive, right? Well, that bloke may be a prisoner, but he still thinks pretty highly of the law.

If he sees you kill all those nambly-pambly elves, he's goin' to tattle to the nearest guard.

Ungrateful prisoner. -_-

Comment: Kill *all* the things.

Comment: Indeed @StrixVaria, so you're saying I should kill them all and just run off with the loot?

Comment: @Ivo Isn't that the way the game is supposed to be played?

Comment: No survivors means no witnesses.

Comment: I've only run into a prisoner escort once, but after talking to the prisoner and freeing him, I was able to slaughter the guards with impunity.  I only ended up with a 5 gold bounty, and I'm not positive I didn't have that already.  ;-)

Comment: Though this is an old post, I have something to say in agreement: No one can notice if there isn't anyone alive *to* notice

Answer (score 11):

If you ask them about the cult of Thalos, enough to become a criminal in their eyes, they'll start attacking you. Since they attacked you first, you'll not have any bounty for killing them and freeing the prisoner.

Comment: You can also provoke them by freeing the prisoner by talking to him.